# Background Image Blocking Android:Hint -- EditText -- Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-xml

I cut an image using InkScape. From this I  made a .9 png image with draw9patch. The .9 resides in my drawables-hdpi folder now. I have made this image the background of an EditText in a res/layout file. The image shows, but it covers over the text from android:hint.

Here is the code for the layout file ---

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/Black"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etCommands"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:background="@drawable/silvertextbox"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="Type a Command"   //This text is covered by @drawable
    android:password="true" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Like I said, my problem is that the android:hint is covered by the android:background. How can I make sure the text of android:hint is over top the background @drawable?

I would post a picture below to show the Graphical Layout, but I do not have 10 reputation points apparently. I am wondering if I will have to do something codewise to make the @drawable transparent / translucent. Or will I have to make the @drawable transparent / translucent
using Inkscape first? Thanks for all help provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting some padding to the `textbox.it`, should resolve the problem.